# Joining three tables with primary in the middle

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am breaking my head on joining of three tables. I have recreated a simple test case where I see the same problem, so it looks I make a fundamental mistake in my join query:

I have three tables:

```html
case:
id (PK)| date_closed
155    | '2018-04-17 10:08' 
156    | '2018-03-17 10:08'     
pizza  | '2018-02-17 10:08' 

registration:
id (FK) | source | quantity
155     | market | 300
155     | sawdust| 200

bagged:
id | case_id (FK) | kg_bagged
X  | 155          | 123
Y  | 155          | 90
```

These tables I want to join to compare the total amounts per 'case' in quantity column and kg_bagged. So the case table has a 1:* many relationship to the other two. Therefore I make a join query like this:

```
SELECT case.id, 
       date_closed,
       SUM(quantity),
       SUM(kg_bagged),
       SUM(kg_bagged)/SUM(quantity) AS reduction_factor
FROM case
    JOIN bagged ON case.id = bagged.case_id
    JOIN registration ON case.id = registration.id
```

Than I would think this would be a correct query, but Postgres tells me I have to add case.id, date_closed to the group by clause. So I add this:

```
GROUP BY case.id, date_closed;
```

This code is running without errors, but it shows 1000 for the quanity at case 155 not the expected 500 (200+300). This behaviour only appears when there is more than 1 record. When joining only 1 table to the case table it also works fine. Can someone see the mistake made at the JOIN query?

I also tried using a subquery for joining two tables and than use a join on the table left, but it gave me similar results

Comment: It's causing a cartesian effect of joining to 2 rows on 2 other tables creating 4 rows total. (doubling your expected answer from 500 to 1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you joining data 2 rows on 2 other tables it match together, so you get the multiplied result. In your example is 2*2 = 4

For easier understand, in your case when you execute the query

```
 SELECT case.id, date_closed, source, quantity, kg_bagged
   FROM case
   JOIN registration ON registration.id = case.id
   JOIN bagged ON bagged.case_id = case.id
```

You will get the data like this:

```
| id  | date_closed        | source | quantity | kg_bagged |
| :-: | :----------------: | :----: | :------: | :-------: |
| 155 | '2018-04-17 10:08' | market | 300      | 123       |
| 155 | '2018-04-17 10:08' | sawdust| 200      | 123       |
| 155 | '2018-04-17 10:08' | market | 300      | 90        |
| 155 | '2018-04-17 10:08' | sawdust| 200      | 90        |
```

In this case, as my experience before, I used to write subquery first to get the sum data first then joining it together.

Such as:

```
   WITH r AS (SELECT id, sum(quantity) as quantity FROM registration GROUP BY id),
    b as (SELECT case_id, SUM(kg_bagged) as kg_bagged FROM bagged GROUP BY case_id)
 SELECT case.id, 
    date_closed,
    quantity,
    kg_bagged,
    kg_bagged/quantity AS reduction_factor
   FROM case
   JOIN b ON case.id = b.case_id
   JOIN r ON case.id = r.id
```

Hopefully, this answer will help you.

Comment: Yes, this solution works. Thanks. Although I still do not grasp the reason why the results are multiplied. I will have to di some more research into that. I see thanks to Andrew that there are quite some resources on this topic under the name Cartesian effect.

Comment: @JosE I've update the answer for more information about this duplicate case. Hopefully it will help you understand easier.

Comment: Ah yes thanks for the update. I see the mistake now, it provides a row for every possible combination.